# How to specify alternate errorfiles for a given backend?

Tags: haproxy

We currently use errorfiles to send various 40x/59x error messages to the client on encountering errors.

Currently these errorfiles are in html format but I'd like to switch them based on a format request parameter from the clients - i.e. in some cases, depending on the presence of a pre-defined request parameter I need to be able to send the errors in XML instead of HTML.

I see no way of doing this conditionally apart from splitting the backend into two - which would be very ugly. Is there a way to do this somehow without splitting the backend?

We're using haproxy v1.5.1

Comment: Sadly, I think this is indeed not possible.